# Redhat repos not found

Tags: rhel, yum, dns, 32bit

I have a Redhat 7 system on loan from a customer in order to install a 32-bit application. To get the application to work, I need to install the gtk2.i686 toolkit.

By doing this command:

```
yum list --showduplicates gtk2
```

I can see the installed 64-bit package is:

```
gtk2.x86_64                               2.24.31-1.el7                                     @rhel-7-server-rpms
```

So I try to install the matching 32-bit version, as follows:

```
yum install gtk2-2.24.31-1.el7.i686
```

This leads to a list of dependencies, and gives the approval prompt:

```
Install  1 Package  (+79 Dependent packages)
Upgrade             (  5 Dependent packages)
Total size: 30 M
Total download size: 24 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]:
```

But, when I agree, it fails on a slew of "could not resolve host errors", e.g.

```
zlib-1.2.7-18.el7.i686.rpm     FAILED                                          
https://rhs6.loc/pulp/repos/Default_Organization/Library/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/os/Packages/z/zlib-1.2.7-18.el7.i686.rpm: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: rhs6.loc; Unknown error"
Trying other mirror.
```

I get similar errors when I do a "yum repolist".

```
# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager

https://rhs6.loc/pulp/repos/Default_Organization/Library/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/ansible/2.6/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: rhs6.loc; Unknown error"
Trying other mirror.
https://rhs6.loc/pulp/repos/Default_Organization/Library/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/extras/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: rhs6.loc; Unknown error"
Trying other mirror.
https://rhs6.loc/pulp/repos/Default_Organization/Library/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/optional/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: rhs6.loc; Unknown error"
Trying other mirror.
https://rhs6.loc/pulp/repos/Default_Organization/Library/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: rhs6.loc; Unknown error"
Trying other mirror.
https://rhs6.loc/pulp/repos/Default_Organization/Library/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/sat-maintenance/6/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: rhs6.loc; Unknown error"
Trying other mirror.
https://rhs6.loc/pulp/repos/Default_Organization/Library/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/sat-tools/6.3/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: rhs6.loc; Unknown error"
Trying other mirror.
https://rhs6.loc/pulp/repos/Default_Organization/Library/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/sat-tools/6.4/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: rhs6.loc; Unknown error"
Trying other mirror.
https://rhs6.loc/pulp/repos/Default_Organization/Library/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/rhscl/1/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: rhs6.loc; Unknown error"
Trying other mirror.
repo id                                            repo name                                              status
epel/x86_64                                        Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64         12,908
google-chrome                                      google-chrome                                               3
!rhel-7-server-ansible-2.6-rpms/x86_64             Red Hat Ansible Engine 2.6 RPMs for Red Hat Enterprise     18
!rhel-7-server-extras-rpms/x86_64                  Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server - Extras (RPMs)       1,063
!rhel-7-server-optional-rpms/x86_64                Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server - Optional (RPMs)    17,348
!rhel-7-server-rpms/x86_64                         Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server (RPMs)               23,690
!rhel-7-server-satellite-maintenance-6-rpms/x86_64 Red Hat Satellite Maintenance 6 (for RHEL 7 Server) (R     26
!rhel-7-server-satellite-tools-6.3-rpms/x86_64     Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.3 (for RHEL 7 Server) (RPMs)     94
!rhel-7-server-satellite-tools-6.4-rpms/x86_64     Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.4 (for RHEL 7 Server) (RPMs)     73
!rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms/x86_64                   Red Hat Software Collections RPMs for Red Hat Enterpri 10,935
repolist: 66,158
```

This command:

```
subscription-manager status
```

Show the status is current.

The command

```
nslookup google.com
```

resolves correctly, and I can browser normally.

Here are the contents of /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search othecompany.dom
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

If I try a curl command on any of the repos urls generated by the yum repolist, they aren't found by the dns server.

So, for some reason, it seems the names in the RedHat 7 repos aren't available on a public DNS. Maybe they're on the other company's DNS server?

Comment: `rhs6.loc` is not a valid DNS name; my initial guess is that it's an internal domain for the other company, and now that the machine is loaned out, the machine cannot reach that network/DNS.

Comment: My guess is that the company named it that for "Red Hat Satellite 6", and that's their, uh, [Red Hat Satellite 6](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_satellite/6.2/html/architecture_guide/chap-red_hat_satellite-architecture_guide-introduction_to_red_hat_satellite) system — but that's just a guess.

Comment: Ah, ok. That has to be it, I was wondering what the RH6 was all about. I will read up on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a "maybe", the names are part of a private DNS space, and they are apparently pointing to an internal Satellite setup.

Changing the DNS for a public DNS name as Google won't solve a private DNS name only known to the organisation's DNS servers.

If they are having internal DNS setup problems, and/or Satellite problems, file a ticket with your client help desk.

Otherwise, you won't normally be able to upgrade/install RH packages under their contract.

See for reference [Red Hat Satellite - The best way to manage your Red Hat infrastructure](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/management/satellite)

also [Understanding Red Hat Content Delivery Network Repositories and their usage with Satellite 6](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1586183)

Comment: I would like to give this a shot using the public repos. I have a Clonzilla backup and can always restore to the original if something goes awry. Can you point me to those? It looks like this link gives a good idea:  https://access.redhat.com/discussions/1405933

Comment: Please read what I just wrote: "Also doing that, could be a violation of some internal software policy, so I do advise filing that help desk ticket." It is not a given the internal repos have identical versions of the outside repos if they are doing revision quality control.

Comment: @JackBeNimble There are not public repos. Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 is a commercial product.

Comment: @mattdm Yeah, I am not being clear, and was forgetting that detail.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Do you mean file a ticket with RedHat, or the company that sent us this sysem? I'm asking because it's a bit of a delicate situation between my company and this other company, and as yet they haven't given use their RedHat credentials.

Comment: @JackBeNimble If we are talking about problems in the client network, it wont be RedHat solving them

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Just to be clear, I'm not on the other company's network, as far as I know. In fact, I'm doing this from home right now. But I had the same issues at my work location. So maybe they setup their DNS server to be applicable to systems in their network only. Or is that what you're saying?

Comment: So is their VM at your home?

Comment: It's not a VM, it's just a PC. Yes, it's at my house.

Comment: It could have put that in the question and that would have helped us both and saved time. I have to get out, need to pay atention to wife, sorry.